# Object is not a function (evaluating 'concreteComponentProvider()') in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using wix react native navigation,it works before adding redux.

```
Navigation.registerComponent('navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen', () => 
AuthScreen);
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      component: {
      name: "navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

when I add redux,

```
const store=configureStore()
Navigation.registerComponent('navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen', () => 
AuthScreen,store,Provider);
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      component: {
      name: "navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen"
      }
    }
   });
 });
```

I'm getting the error Object is not a function(evaluating 'concreteComponentProvider()')

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using the newest version of react-native-navigation, it's probably because you used `registerComponent` instead of `registerComponentWithRedux`.

Try changing your code to:

`Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux('navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen', () => 
AuthScreen,Provider,store);`

And see if it works.

*P.S: In the new version, you have to put the provider before the store.*

[Source](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/third-party?id=registercomponentwithreduxscreenid-generator-provider-store)

Comment: It works.. thanks!! The most important thing in this answer is - 
"In the new version, you have to put the provider before the store."  Thanks!